# $A$ symmetric positive definite show that $\langle x, Ax\rangle \langle y, A^{-1}y\rangle \geq \langle y, x\rangle^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

> $\langle\:,\:\rangle$ denotes the canonical inner product of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
> let $A \in S_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$,
> show that $\forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}, \langle x, Ax\rangle  \langle y, A^{-1}y\rangle \geq \langle y, x\rangle^{2}$

my try:

$\lambda_{min}$ the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, since $A$ is positive definite, $\lambda_{min}>0$

$\lambda_{max}$ the biggest eigenvalue of $A$, since $A$ is positive definite, $\lambda_{max}>0$

we have $\lambda_{min} \: \langle x, x\rangle \leq \langle x, Ax\rangle \le \lambda_{max} \:\langle x, x\rangle$ since $A$ is positive definite

we also have $\frac{1}{\lambda_{max}} \: \langle y, y\rangle \leq \langle y, A^{-1}y\rangle \le \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}} \:\langle y, y\rangle$

thus $  \frac{\lambda_{min}}{\lambda_{max}} \: \langle y, y\rangle \langle x, x\rangle \leq  \langle x, Ax\rangle \langle y, A^{-1}y\rangle \leq \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}} \: \langle y, y\rangle \langle x, x\rangle$

using cauchy Schwarz $\langle y, x\rangle^{2} \leq \langle y, y\rangle \langle x, x\rangle$

In the end, we have $\frac{\lambda_{min}}{\lambda_{max}} \: \langle y, x\rangle^{2} \leq  \langle x, Ax\rangle \langle y, A^{-1}y\rangle$ with $0<\frac{\lambda_{min}}{\lambda_{max}}\le1$
but isn't what it is asked.

Comment: In higher-level mathematics we just do not write $\times$ in these situations. It makes the mathematics *harder* to read.

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, there exists $B$ with $B^TB = A$.

Comment: thank you it get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fact 1: There exists a positive definite matrix $B$ such that $B^{2}=A$.

Proof of Fact 1: Recall that positive definite matrix is orthogonally
diagonalizable. That is, there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ and
a diagonal matrix $D=\mbox{diag}(\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n})$
such that $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n}$ are
eigenvalues of $A$. Note that $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n}$ are
positive. Define $B=P\sqrt{D}P^{-1}$, where $\sqrt{D}=\mbox{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_{1}},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})$,
a diagonal matrix whose main diagonal consists of $\sqrt{\lambda_{1}},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}$.
Clearly $B$ is also positive definite and $B^{2}=A$.

---

Claim 2: For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have that $\langle Ax,y\rangle^{2}\leq\langle Ax,x\rangle\langle Ay,y\rangle$.

Proof of Claim 2: Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be given. Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle Ax,y\rangle^{2} & = & \langle B^{2}x,y\rangle^{2}\\
 & = & \langle Bx,B^{t}y\rangle^{2}\\
 & = & \langle Bx,By\rangle^{2}\\
 & \leq & \langle Bx,Bx\rangle\langle By,By\rangle\\
 & = & \langle B^{t}Bx,x\rangle\langle B^{t}By,y\rangle\\
 & = & \langle BBx,x\rangle\langle BBy,y\rangle\\
 & = & \langle Ax,x\rangle\langle Ay,y\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
In the above, we have used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Remark: The above inequality can be proved directly without considering
matrix $B$. For, let $\sigma(x,y)=\langle Ax,y\rangle$. $\sigma$
is positive, symmetric, bilinear, and shares a lot of properties
similar to inner product. Therefore, we can repeat the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
Consider $0\leq\sigma(\lambda x+y,\lambda x+y)=\lambda^{2}\sigma(x,x)+2\lambda\sigma(x,y)+\sigma(y,y)$.
If $\sigma(x,x)\neq0$, then the above is a quadratic in $\lambda$.
It is always non-negative$\Rightarrow$discriminant is non-positive...

---

For your problem. Let $x',y'\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be given. Put $x=x'$
and $y=A^{-1}y'$ in Claim 2, then we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle Ax',A^{-1}y'\rangle^{2} & \leq & \langle Ax',x'\rangle\langle AA^{-1}y',A^{-1}y'\rangle\\
 & = & \langle Ax',x'\rangle\langle y',A^{-1}y'\rangle.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that $\left(A^{-1}\right)^{t}=\left(A^{t}\right)^{-1}$, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle Ax',A^{-1}y'\rangle & = & \langle(A^{-1})^{t}Ax',y'\rangle\\
 & = & \langle(A^{t})^{-1}Ax',y'\rangle\\
 & = & \langle(A)^{-1}Ax',y'\rangle\\
 & = & \langle x',y'\rangle.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

*1<sup>st</sup> Solution.* Note that

$$(x, y) := \langle x, Ay \rangle$$

defines another inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$ \langle x, y \rangle^2
= ( x, A^{-1}y )^2
\stackrel{\text{C-S}}\leq (x, x)(A^{-1}y, A^{-1}y)
= \langle x, Ax \rangle \langle y, A^{-1}y \rangle. $$

---

*2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.* Consider the function

$$ f(t) = \langle x + tA^{-1}y, Ax + ty \rangle. $$

By writing $z = x + tA^{-1}y$, we have

$$ f(t) = \langle z, Az \rangle \geq 0 $$

since $A$ is positive definite. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
f(t)
&= \langle x, Ax \rangle + t\langle x, y \rangle + t \langle Ax, A^{-1}y \rangle + t^2 \langle y, A^{-1}y \rangle \\
&= \langle x, Ax \rangle + 2t\langle x, y \rangle + t^2 \langle y, A^{-1}y \rangle.
\end{align*}

Since $f(t)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $t$, its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) $D$ is non-positive, i.e.,

$$ D = (2\langle x, y \rangle)^2 - 4\langle x, Ax \rangle\langle y, A^{-1}y \rangle \leq 0. $$

This immediately implies the desired inequality.